# Are raffle tickets sold by charitable organizations in Virginia required to have date, time of drawing printed on them

Tags: gambling, virginia, charity

some raffle tickets have "drawing when all tickets are sold" printed on them.  No time, date or place of drawing.

Answer (score 3):

Virginia code [section § 18.2-340.19.](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title18.2/chapter8/section18.2-340.19/) authorizes the the Virginia Department of Agriculture and Consumer Services to adopt regulations covering "charitable gambling" which includes raffles. Those regulations may be found at https://www.vdacs.virginia.gov/pdf/Charitable%20Gaming%20Regulations.pdf

Regulation 11VAC15‐40‐80. (Recordkeeping) Section C provides that:

> C. All raffle tickets shall have a detachable section; be consecutively numbered with the detachable section having the same number; provide space for the purchaser's name, complete address, and telephone number; and state (i) the name and address of the organization; (ii) the prize or prizes to be awarded; (iii) the date, time and location of the prize drawing; (iv) the
> selling price of the ticket; and (v) the charitable gaming permit number. Winning tickets and unsold tickets shall be maintained for a minimum of three years from the close of the fiscal year.

So it would seem that raffle tickets are supposed to include "the date, time and location of the prize drawing".